# Using Declared Variables in a Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

The Following query is "supposed to" use the subquery to find items in a specific column, and pivot them so that each of those items becomes their own column. The subquery works fine on its own, but when I try to add it to a larger query that would then take the results of the subquery and insert them into a table, I start getting a couple syntax errors. Below is the entire query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

Insert Into tbl_AS ( Billing_Account_ID, Bill_Date, MTN, User_Name  ,Adjustment_To_Balance_Previous_Description,Adjustments_To_Previous_Balance
    ,Adjustment_Type)

Select
    As_Selection.Billing_Account_ID
    ,As_Selection.Bill_Date
    ,As_Selection.MTN
    ,As_Selection.User_Name
    ,As_Selection.Adjustment_To_Balance_Previous_Description
    ,As_Selection.Adjustments_To_Previous_Balance
    ,As_Selection.Adjustment_Type


    FROM( --Subquery in question

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct 
                        ',' +
                        QUOTENAME([Section_1])
                FROM [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO]
                where [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO].[Section_1] <> 'Prior Activity' AND [dbo].[1_Import_tbl_RDO].[Section_1] <> 'Group Details' AND [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO].[Section_1] <> 'Wireless Line Summary' AND  [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO].[Section_1] <> 'Wireless Details' AND  [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO].[Section_1] <> 'Equipment & Accessories Charges'
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE 
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

Set @query = ' Select [Billing Account Number], [Period End Date], [Wireless Number], [User Name]' + @cols +'
    From 
        (
            Select 
                 [Amount] as SumOfAmount,[Billing Account Number], [Period End Date],  [Wireless Number], [User Name]
                 From [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO]
                 Where [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO].[Section ID] = ''IRA'' AND [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO].[Section_1] IS Not Null
                 ) t
                 PIVOT 
                 (
                 SUM(SumOfAmount)
                    FOR [Section_1] IN(' + @cols + ')
                    ) p '

    Execute (@query)

    ) as AS_Selection
```

The errors are showing up as Incorrect Syntax at `@cols = STUFF` and `FOR XML`. Am I way off in how this subquery needs to be written?

EDIT:

Following the suggestion from below, I have reordered my query to look like this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct 
                        ',' +
                        QUOTENAME([Section_1])
                FROM [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO]
                where [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO].[Section_1] <> 'Prior Activity' AND [dbo].[1_Import_tbl_RDO].[Section_1] <> 'Group Details' AND [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO].[Section_1] <> 'Wireless Line Summary' AND  [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO].[Section_1] <> 'Wireless Details' AND  [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO].[Section_1] <> 'Equipment & Accessories Charges'
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE 
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

Set @query = 'INSERT INTO tbl_AS (
    Billing_Account_ID
    ,Bill_Date
    ,MTN
    ,User_Name
    ,As_Selection.Adjustment_To_Balance_Previous_Description
    ,As_Selection.Adjustments_To_Previous_Balance
    ,As_Selection.Adjustment_Type
    )


            Select
                As_Selection.[Billing Account Number]
                ,As_Selection.[Period End Date]
                ,As_Selection.[Wireless Number]
                ,As_Selection.[User Name]
                ,As_Selection.Adjustment_To_Balance_Previous_Description
                ,As_Selection.Adjustments_To_Previous_Balance
                ,As_Selection.Adjustment_Type


                FROM( 


                    Select [Billing Account Number], [Period End Date], [Wireless Number], [User Name]' + @cols +'
                        From 
                            (
                                Select 
                                     [Amount] as SumOfAmount,[Billing Account Number], [Period End Date],  [Wireless Number], [User Name]
                                     From [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO]
                                     Where [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO].[Section ID] = ''IRA'' AND [dbo].[Import_tbl_RDO].[Section_1] IS Not Null
                                     ) t
                                     PIVOT 
                                     (
                                     SUM(SumOfAmount)
                                        FOR [Section_1] IN(' + @cols + ')
                                        ) p 
                        ) as AS_Selection'
                Execute (@query)
```

While this seems to have gotten me closer, I am still running into issues. Now the only error I get is one telling me that the Column `User Name` does not exist. I know the column exists, so I think this is just an error being thrown by something else, potentially the `'+@cols+'`. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I have Printed the values for both @query and @cols. The Results for @query are the same as the edited query I posted a few minutes ago, except the print did not show the Declare or print statements. The @cols Print looked like this:

`[Adjustment To Balance Previous Description], [Adjustments To Previous Balance], [Adjustment Type]`

Comment: In SQL Server, a `select` statement can either assign variables or return values.  It cannot do both.

Comment: When I just run the subquery, which includes that Select statement, it runs fine.

Comment: User_Name should be a reserved word in MS SQL. Try [User_Name].

Comment: @HardCode, thanks for commenting. I tried that, in fact I tried just deleting that column out of the query entirely. When I ran it again, it gave me the same error, but for `Wireless Number` rather than `User Name`.

Comment: Change your `Execute (@query)` to `Print @query` and edit your post with result so we can debug the final query you are trying to execute.   You shouldn't still be doing `SELECT @Cols = ...` inside your declaration of `@query`.

Comment: @TabAlleman I have updated the EDIT version of my code with the new changes. Leaving the `Select @cols` within the `@query` declaration was a typo, I forgot to delete it out when I pasted it on here. I have been working with the updated code on my end. You should be able to see the changes now in question post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are way off.   A sub-query cannot be a multi-statement batch.

You need to do things in this order:

1. Set @Cols, which can stay the way it is.
2. Set @query, and include your entire query in it, including the outer select, and even the insert.
3. Execute @query.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have reordered my query to follow your suggestions, but I am still running into issues. Now it's telling me that column `User Name` is an invalid column, which I know it isn't. I'm thinking that it might have something to do with the `+@cols+' that is next to it in the subquery. Any suggestions as to what might be going on? I have edited my original question to reflect the changes you suggest.

Comment: As suggested by JC Castro, you need a comma after `[User Name]`.   The truncation error means you are trying to insert too large a string into too small a column, so look at the size of the columns in the table you are inserting into, and look at the data you are trying to insert and either shorten the data or lengthen the column size.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the value of @cols, it seems a coma (,) is missing after the [user name] column, before the concatenation with @cols variable

```
... Set @query = ' Select [Billing Account Number], [Period End Date], [Wireless Number], [User Name], ' + @cols +'
From ...
```

Comment: One would think, but I tried that, it gave me a syntax error.

Comment: Upon another review, it doesn't give me a syntax error, it gives me a `String or binary data would be truncated` error